How to return multiple rows with aggregated values in MySql
The title might be a bit confusing but I need help with the following aggregation inside a MySQL query. I need to be able to create a single row that contain 3 different schedules for each distinct object_id.
I have the following table, lets call it schedules:



id
objectId
day
opening_at
closing_at




1
428
1
1970-01-01 07:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


2
428
2
1970-01-01 07:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


3
428
3
1970-01-01 07:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


4
428
4
1970-01-01 07:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


5
428
5
1970-01-01 07:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


6
428
6
1970-01-01 08:30:00
1970-01-01 22:00:00


7
428
7
1970-01-01 08:30:00
1970-01-01 21:30:00



Day column:

1 - Sunday
2-6 - week days
7 - Saturday

So for the above example I would like to obtain the following record:
object_id | weekdays_schedule | saturday_schedule | sunday_schedule
428       | 07:30-22:00       | 08:30-21:30       | 07:30-22:00

For example, the following query returns 3 rows, each with a different schedule:
SELECT DISTINCT object_id,
CONCAT(
   DATE_FORMAT(opening_at, '%H:%i'),
   '-',
   DATE_FORMAT(closing_at, '%H:%i')
) AS schedule
FROM schedules

I thought of using group_concat but I can't seem to create multiple values for the same object_id.

1 - Sunday 2-6 - week days 7 - Saturday   --- what is column name of the numeric values ? is that id or day column? @Vlad

I would like to obtain the following record ?? What do you want to receive if the schedule for 2 weekdays differs?

dbfiddle for some ideas.

@ArtBindu its the day column

Yes, I already update the MySQL query for your result @Vlad

@Akina, basically we will get the first schedule for that bulk of days, so 2-6 is a group, I will set the schedule that I find for day "2" since that comes up first ... might seem weird since the result is not 100% accurate for some days but its fine

Schematically SELECT objectId, t1.schedule, t2.schedule, t3.schedule FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 USING (objectId) JOIN table t3 USING (objectId) WHERE t1.day=2 AND t2.day=7 AND t3.day=1. In this case schedule is a pair combined from starting and finishing columns.

Now I update my query according to your output:

Here I take two object_id, to write the query more generic.
So, My input table is:

First separate the data according to day_type (week_days, sunday or saturday), then split into 3 tables for your output according to day_type and merge all of them to show your respective output format.
This is MySQL query
with T1 as (
  select *,
  cast(opening_at as time) as start_time,
  cast(closing_at as time) as end_time,
  case 
     when(day%7 = 1) then 'Sunday'
     when(day%7 = 0) then 'Saturday'
     else 'week days'
  end as day_type
  from T
),
T2 as (
   select objectid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as ids_list,
       day_type,
       -- min(start_time) as start_time,
       -- max(end_time) as end_time
       -- change hh:mm:ss to hh:mm for your output
       REGEXP_REPLACE(cast(min(start_time) as CHAR),'(\:\\d+)$', '') as start_time,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(cast(min(end_time) as CHAR),'(\:\\d+)$', '') as end_time
   from T1
   group by objectid, day_type
),
T31 as (select * from T2 where day_type = 'Sunday'),
T32 as (select * from T2 where day_type = 'Saturday'),
T33 as (select * from T2 where day_type = 'week days')

select T33.objectid,
  concat(T31.start_time, '-', T31.end_time) AS weekdays_schedule,
  concat(T32.start_time, '-', T32.end_time) AS saturday_schedule,
  concat(T33.start_time, '-', T33.end_time) AS sunday_schedule
-- changes base table according to your requirement
from T33
LEFT JOIN T32
  ON T33.objectid = T32.objectid
LEFT JOIN T31
  ON T33.objectid = T31.objectid

So, output is:

Source Code: db<>fiddle

thank you for the response, what I would like to obtain is actually the schedule for those days, grouped just like I've left them in my post ... so Sunday will be a column name, and it will have the value 07:30-22:00 on the row ... Saturday will be another column, with its own value on that same row ..

@Vlad I have update query according to your requirements

Older query reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/sosPWtW_ (for me)

Nice, yes, this looks more like the result that I am after! Thank you very much! So GROUP_CONCAT was needed.

Yes, use GROUP_CONCAT, then split w.r.t day_type and then JOIN... Truthy, I did not write such query to rotate horizontal data to vertical data... It's my first query like that ...  wlcm @Vlad
